# async call to Controller - for state and county

Tags: grails, asynchronous, controller

In Grails - I need to make a controller method that will populate State and County dropdown form fields so that when a State is selected it will fill only that State's counties into the County dropdown.

A colleague told me that's an asynchronous call in Grails, but I'm a novice in Grails and I really don't know what that is or how to start one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code snippets:

using Grails 2.43 currently.  I have two domain classes (State and County), and two Select dropdowns for State and County.

Form elements:

```
<g:select name="locationState" class="form-control" from="${....State.list().sort{it.orderNumber}}">

<g:select name="locationCounty" class="form-control" from="${...State.FindByName(it.orderNumber).counties}">
```

Here are the example classes:

```
 class State {

        static hasMany = [county:County]

        String name
        String value
        int orderNumber = 0

        static constraints = {
            name nullable:false, maxSize:50, blank:false
            value nullable:false, maxSize:100, blank:false
        }

        String toString(){
            "$value"
        }

        static mapping = {
            table 'state'
            cache: 'read-write'
            columns{
                id column:'id'
                name column:'name'
                value column:'value'
                orderNumber column:'order_number'
            }
            id generator: 'assigned'
        }
    }


    class County {

        State state
        String county

        static constraints = {
            state nullable:false
            county nullable:false, maxSize:100, blank:false
        }

        String toString(){
            "${state.name} - $county"
        }

        static mapping = {
            table 'county'
            cache: 'read-write'
            columns{
                id column:'id'
                county column:'county'
                state column:'state_id'
            }
            id generator: 'assigned'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but your classes are full of bloat. Remove the `columns` sections; you're defining the db column names to be _exactly_ what they would be without your "overrides". Same for `table`. `cache: 'read-write'` is more self-documenting, but I'd use `cache true` which is more idiomatic and does the same thing. Also, `nullable:false` is the default, so there's no reason to include it. And your `toString()` in `State` is weird. Why create a GString containing a single variable, only to have Groovy convert that back to that variable's value when the method is invoked? Return `value`.

Comment: Did you read http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html ?

Comment: yes I did but I must confess that I didn't understand it too well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async guide linked in the comments is for make programatic, asynchronous calls. For example, if you had two computationally expensive method calls (or ones that would require network I/O) you can use threads to run them (roughly) in parallel. Grails provides many different helpers to make this kind of asynchronous programming very easy.

However, this is not likely something you need for your GORM queries. You want to populate a second select box. You could accomplish this two ways, by reloading the page after the state is selected, or by using JavaScript to populate the box. I am assuming you want to do the latter. Grails *does* provide tools (such as the [<g:remoteFunction />](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) tag) to handle this without writing your own JavaScript but the Grails AJAX library has since been **deprecated** and its use is not recommended.

Instead, you should just write your own JavaScript. I'll show you a technique using jQuery:

In your view, initialize both selects, but the second should be initialized as empty. We are also going to give them IDs to make them easier to select from jQuery:

```
<g:select name="locationState"
    class="form-control"
    from="${....State.list().sort{it.orderNumber}}"
    id="location-state" />
<g:select name="locationCounty"
    class="form-control"
    from="${[]}"
    id="location-county" />
```

Then, we will need to expose an action on the controller to load the counties when the user selects a state:

```
def loadCountiesByState() {
    def state = params.state
    def counties = State.findByValue(state).counties
    render g.select(name: 'locationCounty', class: 'form-control',
            from: counties, id: 'location-county')
}
```

You should be able to test this part just by pointing your browser to `/app-name/controller-name/loadCountiesByState?state=CA`. I don't know exactly how your data is modeled so you might need to alter the `State.findByValue(state)` part to fit your needs.

Now we just need to wire up the control with some JavaScript. Make sure you have jQuery included.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#location-sate').change(function() {
            var state = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/app-name/controller-name/loadCountiesByState',
                date: { state: state },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#location-county').replaceWith(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will replace the dropdown with a new select that should be fully populated with the counties.

Comment: I'm gonna have to separate the methods.  I don't think Grails will let me have a method within a method.  How do I call *TO* a method from inside another method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What error are you seeing? You should be putting the `loadCountiesByState` method in the controller along with the other actions.

Comment: Nevermind, I got that part figured out.  :)  But with the render g.select statement -- do I need to import something or a library? Grails has that part underlined like it can't find it or something.

Comment: You might have to add: `def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')`

Comment: when I try that it won't let me save it. Gives me a Save As error. "Reason: some characters cannot be mapped using 'Cpl1252' character encoding."

Comment: It's probably the quotes or something. Just type it by hand. Side note: just use UTF-8 for your file encoding.

Comment: hmm... that worked but still didn't take away the underline of the g.select part

Comment: What IDE are you using? And if this solves your problem please mark my answer.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention.  I am on Grails 2.4.3 on a Win7/64 enterprise OS environment

Comment: One bit of clarification that *might* be causing me problems?  Will the function still work if the form item doesn't reference it?    I wrote it into the form with <g:javascript>  as a function called checkCounty() then I called to it on the State form item with onchange=checkCounty()

Comment: Are you not using jQuery? Using `onchange` is old-style. I'm not sure that `$(this)` works if it's with an `onchange`

Comment: yeah I have the JQuery lib added.   Just was confused on A) how to insert that code into a gsp form and B) how to make sure the State form item will see/use it.

Comment: Put it in a `<script></script` block and just make sure that it's loaded AFTER the jQuery scripts. If you are using asset-pipeline you can just include it in `application.js`. That first line, `$('#location-sate').change()` is what binds the action to element with the ID of location-state.

Comment: so it'd be something like this in a GSP page?  Sorry about the formatting. :)

<g: javascript>
  $(function() {
        $('#location-sate').change(function() {
            var state = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/app-name/controller-name/loadCountiesByState',
                date: { state: state },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#location-county').replaceWith(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</g:javascript>

Comment: Yes. What is the issue you are having? Is it a JavaScript error? What does the JavaScript console in your browser say?

Comment: got the ajax call to work.  No errors in Firebug now.  But it still leaves the County dropdown entirely blank.

Comment: Got it all squared away now.  Thanks so much for your help, Greg.  -Ryan